# How many elements of array are not null?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, arrays

An array is defined of assumed elements like I have array like ***String[] strArray = new String[50];***.

Now from 50 elements only some elements are assigned and remaining are left null then I want the number of assigned elements.

Like here only 30 elements are assigned then I want that figure.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use [Enumerable.Count](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181.aspx):

```
string[] strArray = new string[50];
...
int result = strArray.Count(s => s != null);
```

This [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) iterates the array and counts the number of elements the specified predicate applies to.

Comment: The code uses LINQ. You need to add `using System.Linq;` at the top of  your source file to make the LINQ extension methods visible.

Comment: Is it same to do like everytime checking  for the each element of strArray that it is null or not in the for loop ?

Comment: To "right fit" the Array to include only those assigned elements, I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9571134/307454) helpful.

Answer (score 8):

Using LINQ you can try

```
int count = strArray.Count(x => x != null);
```

Comment: You beat my 5.37 seconds :) But does the OP want null or non null elements?

Answer (score 1):

Use LINQ:

```
int i = (from s in strArray where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) select s).Count();
```

Comment: Mmmmm thanks?!?! The other guys had more concise answers than me.