# Adding a new element to the end of a C# array

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, razorengine

Im trying to do exactly what the title says

```
    int[] weeks = {};
    weeks[weeks.Length]=1;
```

this doesnt work. There is also no .Add Method.

Any ideas? or is this not possible

Comment: What is a "razor array"? Do you mean that you're trying to do this in a view?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9570944/adding-elements-to-a-c-sharp-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays in C# by definition are of a fixed size, and cannot be dynamically expanded.

I would suggest using a `List<>`, as they can be dynamically expanded, much like vectors in other programming languages.

```
List<int> weeks = new List<int>();
weeks.add(1);
```

See more [here.](http://www.dotnetperls.com/list)

Answer (score 3):

Line 1 declares and initializes a new 1-dimensional array of int without specific size. 
  Line 2 resizes the array (weeks) to its actual size, plus 1. 
  Line 3 assigns the value 1 to the element at the last position (that we created in Line 2)

Remember:  int[5] weeks; -> to access last element you have to use index 4 -> weeks[4] = 1

```
int[] weeks = {};
Array.Resize(ref weeks,weeks.Length + 1);
weeks[weeks.Length - 1]=1;
```

Comment: Would benefit from some explanation.

Answer (score 1):

First of all there is no such thing razor array. Razor is a view engine and array is a data structure.
Arrays have fixed length so if you declare an array with the length of 5:

`int[] weeks = new int[5];`

Trying to add an element to a fifth place will result in `IndexOutOfRangeException`

If you need some data-structure with variable size you could look at all the objects that implement `IList` interface  for example a [List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), an [ArrayList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and others.

IList interface also defines Add method that you requested.